# Clipping NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nswindow, clipping

I am quite new to Cocoa MacOSX development and I am facing the following challenge:
There is an app that I have not written and I need to do scissoring of the main window. Said another way, I need to 'hide', let's say the half bottom of the window or any other sides of the window (dynamically). I don't want that the content of the window (views & sub-views) to be resized!

I tried things like playing with the layer.masksToBounds of the window's content view. Also played with the NSView.setBounds. No luck till now :(
Also going this way: [Is it possible to clip a child NSWindow to its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462226/is-it-possible-to-clip-a-child-nswindow-to-its-parent) could also be a solution but the question does not have any answer :-/
Any help of a direction to look for would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? Im trying to make NSWindow frame smaller but keep it's contentView the same size (clip the view) but i don't know how, and stumbled here, but no answer :|